# Ensure main JVM program will blow, even with launched with Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, error-handling, kotlin-coroutines

I have a very simple Kotlin program like

```
  fun main() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    val job = scope.launch() { // I only check if this Job isActive later
              withTimeout(2000) {
                  terminate(task)
              }
          }

  }

  private suspend fun terminate(task: Task): Nothing = suspendCoroutine {
      throw IllegalAccessError("Task ${task.name} should honor timeouts!")
  }
```

When **terminate()** is called I want my program to blow. I don't want to recover. However, I can't only see

```
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-2" 
abc.xyz.mainKt$terminate$$inlined$suspendCoroutine$lambda$1: Task Robot should honor timeouts!
// More stacktrace ...
```

in logs, since Coroutines is "swallowing" this Exception.

Therefore, my question is : how would be a guaranteed way to blow my program when a timeout happens, with a design driven by Kotlin Coroutines?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#timeout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great to ask a question here after having done your own research. As you can see from @IR42 comment your question may already have been answered by the official ___Kotlin Language Guide___. If that's not the case then make sure to include a reference in your question's description and explain your specific problem that's not covered by the official guide.

Comment: You've never joined the coroutine job to the main thread, you should be doing `job.join()` in order to propagate the exception to main thread in order to make JVM exit.

Comment: Use `System.exit()` to unconditionally terminate the JVM. However, it's usually a _very_ bad idea to do that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    withTimeout(2000) {
        terminate(task)
    }
}
```